# How can I restart only one service by using skaffold?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, skaffold

I use skaffold for k8s based microservices app. I enter `skaffold dev` and `skaffold run` to run and `skaffold delete` to restart all microservices.

If I need to restart only one service, what must I do?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://skaffold.dev/docs/quickstart/):

- Use **skaffold dev** to build and **deploy** your app **every time your code changes**,
- Use **skaffold run** to build and **deploy** your app once, **similar to a CI/CD pipeline**

---

**1**. Deploy your services:

```
    skaffold run --filename=skaffold_test_1.yaml
```

(in addition you can have multiple workflow configurations).

**2.** Change your skaffold workflow configuration and run:

```
skaffold delete --filename=skaffold_test2.yaml
```

Using this approach your deployments will be not removed like in the skaffold dev command after stopping skaffold.

Basically managing the content of the skaffold workflow configuration (by adding or removing additional entries allows you to deploy or remove particular service).

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1
kind: Config
.
.
.

deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s-service1.yaml
#   - k8s-service2.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could delete one resource as you have stated. It got unbound from the main `skaffold dev` terminal. I run it as you have stated but it didn't get bound again. I had to restart everything again

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean. If there still is an issue please update the question. The main difference is how `dev`  works vs `run`. In the first example dev is watching for changes in the skaffold file while `run` is performing all tasks only once. So you can run your steps, than change your skaffold.yaml and perform for example delete one resource (as stated in the example above) it will remove all manifest from the skaffold.yaml (it's your responsibility to maintain this file properly).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skaffold dev`'s `--watch-image` flag to restrict the artifacts to monitor.  This takes a comma-separated list of images, specified by the *artifact.image*.